# Force Spark to distribute tasks on all YARN executors

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop-yarn

I have a Spark cluster with 5 nodes. But when I run an application, only 2 executors are used. How to distribute tasks on all executors?

[image: spark tasks]

(these are not always the same 2 that are used, but never more than 2)

Comment: How did you execute the job? please provide the launch script or the code.

Comment: Data: **Input Size / Records: 1146.9 KB / 9292** (I have tried an other app with 800MB of input data and I have the same problem). I execute the job like this: `./bin/spark-submit --class com.test.RunApp --master yarn-cluster app.jar`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yarn defaults to using 2 cores. You have to set `num-executors`, and should probably also look into the `executor-cores` option also.

Comment: Argument `--num-executors n` works. Or it's better with `spark.dynamicAllocation.enabled` (see https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/job-scheduling.html#configuration-and-setup)